# How do I default a parameter in a discord.py command

Tags: python, parameters, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command with discord.py with a parameter that defaults to a set value but it won't work. Here's my code for the start of the command. I am not handling any exceptions or doing anything special with the command.

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, arg="none"):
```

These are my imports.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you gave a `string` value. You have to do `async def play(ctx, arg=None):`.